How to run a CI Specific ServiceNow Query
I've used this tool before to find Incidents assigned to me and such, but right now I'm in the need of finding any possible kind of SNow tickets that may have affected a specific CI of ours after Oct 2nd, when it started presenting issues.
Anybody has a clue of which table could contain this info, partial info or how to perform a join to display this info?
I'm using the SNow user interface, on the Reports -> Create New menu.
